# golang server middlerware request cancellation

Tags: go, server, middleware

I created in the example at the bottom a little server which is running on port 3000. You can access it over "htto://localhost:3000/time". The whole Request is covered with two middlewares. First "cancelHandler" and Second "otherHandler" is called - which is responding with some dummy data after 4 seconds.

**To my problem:** When i request the page in a browser and then cancel the request (before the 4sec). The server is still handling the goroutine/request in the background. I spent already hours to find a solution on google but i can just not wrap my head around the context. (context.WithCancel()) I get that i have to create a chan and listen to it but how does this work with the requests. thats already a goroutine, do i have to create another goroutine in the request/goroutine? Also another question is, should i really use Context for that or is there an easier solution with the cancelNotifier?

Maybe someone can describe it for me and others which maybe have the same understanding problem.

Solution should be that the cancel Handler is stopping the goroutine/request, when the browser cancels the request.

Thank you very much for your time!

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
   "fmt"
)

func otherHandler(format string) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(4)*time.Second)
        tm := time.Now().Format(format)
        w.Write([]byte("The time is: " + tm))
        fmt.Println("response:", "The time is: "+tm)

    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func cancelHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("start: called cancelHandler")

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)

        fmt.Println("end: called cancelHandler")

    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    th := otherHandler(time.RFC1123)
    mux.Handle("/time", cancelHandler(th))

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to "stop" a function is to return from it. Thus, time.Sleep cannot be interrupted. Use a select statement instead:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", otherHandler(time.RFC1123))
}

func otherHandler(format string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            select {
            case <-time.After(4 * time.Second):
                    // time's up
            case <-r.Context().Done():
                    // client gave up
                    return
            }

            tm := time.Now().Format(format)
            w.Write([]byte("The time is: " + tm))
            fmt.Println("response:", "The time is: "+tm)
    }
}
```

In general, check the request context (or one that is derived from it) in strategic places. If the context is canceled, don't proceed any further and `return`.

Comment: And maybe I should mention that Go will cancel the context for you when the client interrupts the connection. You don't need context.WithCancel/Timeout/Deadline unless you want to add your own abort condition.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I totally get your example. But it does not solve my problem yet. what if i have instead of the "time.After(4s)" another Handler which is handling the main response and this is heavy load. If a User closes his browser, it still running at least one full time. Because i would have to call it before the select statement. So before the select statement already the "heavyLoad" Function or Handler is getting handled. Right after that is the select and here would be the logic if the browser was closed... Still doesn´t make 100% sense to me.

Comment: The only Solution which would make sense to me is, call the "heavy load" function in another goroutine. Get a process ID from the goroutine (Dont know if thats even possible). Now the Select would run right after the goroutine got fired and if there would be a browser cancel, the process of the go routine has to get killed

Comment: You pass the context to heavyLoad and heavyLoad has to check for cancelation. You won't get by without heavyLoad co-operating. That's a good thing too. Imagine heavyLoad updates some database and then sends an email, notifying users about the update. You don't want to interrupt that anymore after the DB has been updated, even if the client gives up. You can't do that "from the outside". https://play.golang.org/p/cnZ9DYW62jH

Comment: You are right about that! Thanks for your help Pete ;)